# Dropdown binding with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Suppose I have this controller:

```
myApp.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.cars = [
        { carId: '1', carModel: 'BMW', carOwner: 'Nader' },
        { carId: '2', carModel: 'Mercedes', carOwner: 'Hisham' },
        { carId: '3', carModel: 'Opel', carOwner: 'Saad' }
    ];
});
```

and this HTML:

```
<select ng-options="car as car.carModel for car in cars" ng-model="car"></select>
<br />
<label> Car ID </label> <input type="text" ng-model="car.carId" />
<br />
<label> Car Model </label> <input type="text" ng-model="car.carModel" />
<br />
<label> Car Owner </label> <input type="text" ng-model="car.carOwner" />
```

When a user selects a car it should automatically bind values of the selected car to the text boxes, which already happens in this case. However, when I change the value in the text box for the `carModel`, the `carModel` name in the dropdown changes.

How can I change the input for the `carModel` without changing the value in the dropdown? Note that I want to bind the information of the currently selected car to the textboxes whenever the user selects a different value from the dropdown.

---

**Use Case**

Suppose a list of cars is retrieved from a database and I want the user to edit the selected car, so first I want to show the car information when the user selects it from from the dropdown, then change whatever he wants and call a web service to update the selected car.

Comment: what is use case for changing the text boxes if model object itself isn't to be changed? Why can't you bind the text boxes to a copy of `car` using events?

Comment: @charlietfl check my updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `angular.copy` for this:

JavaScript: define `callTest` function in your `testCtrl`

```js
$scope.cars = [ ... ];

$scope.callTest = function(objCar) {
  console.log(objCar);
  $scope.carModel = angular.copy(objCar); // this carModel is used in the html
};
```

HTML:

```html
<select ng-change="callTest(car)" ng-options="car as car.carModel for car in cars" ng-model="car"></select>
<br />
<label> Car ID </label>
<input type="text" ng-model="carModel.carId" />
<br />
<label> Car Model </label>
<input type="text" ng-model="carModel.carModel" />
<br />
<label> Car Owner </label>
<input type="text" ng-model="carModel.carOwner" />
```

Use `ng-change event` on select and call `callTest()` function in the controller.

Here is the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/e066nSjHGK7r3ao7v1vw?p=preview)

Comment: this is a good option but I wonder is there any way we can do the same without copying objects

Comment: @NaderHisham try one time binding: `<select ng-options="::car as car.carModel for car in cars" ng-model="car"></select>`

Answer (score 2):

The basic steps I would use would be:

1. Use `ng-change` event of `<select>` to create copy of `car` using `angular.copy()`
2. Bind copied object to text boxes `ng-model="carCopy.propName"`
3. Edit the car
4. On save,  use `angular.extend()` to merge updates back to original `car`

Answer (score 1):

This is also possible by using directives. Pass car as string parameter.
Directive template shows form. Variable in select won't change since it's Object variables are passed as string to directive.

template.html

```
<br />
<label> Car ID </label> <input type="text" ng-model="carId" />
<br />
<label> Car Model </label> <input type="text" ng-model="carModel" />
<br />
<label> Car Owner </label> <input type="text" ng-model="carOwner" />
```

html view

```
 <select ng-options="car as car.carModel for car in cars" ng-model="car"></select>
 <ca car-id="{{car.carId}}" car-model="{{car.carModel}}" car-owner="{{car.carOwner}}"></ca>
```

And the directive which You can customize.

```
.directive('ca', function() {
  return {
    scope:{
            carId:'@',
            carModel:'@',
            carOwner:'@'
        },
    templateUrl: 'template.html'
  };
});
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jqWRQ05U9kqgjFS104dh?p=preview)

This example may work with Angular 2.0 or be easier to migrate.